# How to hide an invoice linein odoo v12 if there's more than 5 lines

Tags: python, cloud, odoo

i have an issue with some odoo studio custimization. The invoice line shoudn"t appear in the impression unless it has only 3 lines, for more the whole content should appear in another repport.
i started creating a checkbox and i called it 'Annexe' and in the visibility condition under the invoices lines, that they will appear only if the checkbox is checked. but i need an automated action to check the Annexe once the invoices lines are more than 3 or anyother suggestion. ( i am using the cloud version)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you please update your question with attempt code, current output and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any code yet, the best I can offer is a broad answer.

As you have probably done, the `annexe` field has the following attributes: `computed=_compute_count_order_lines, store=True, readonly=True` and you have also declared a function like:

```
@api.depends('order_line')
def _compute_count_order_lines(self):
  for order in self:
    order.annexe = len(order.order_line.filtered(lambda x: x.state != 'cancel')) > 3
```

Thus `annexe` will signal if the number of order lines is greater than 3.

Then you need to modify the report from which the invoice is generated:

1. In debug mode, go to "Settings / Technical / Reporting / Reports"
   and search for "Model: `sale.order`".
2. Click on the record for which its template name is `sale.report_saleorder`
3. Click on the "QWeb Views" button
4. Click on the record for which its "External ID" is `sale.report_saleorder_document`
5. Look for `<table class="table table-sm o_main_table">` that's the table with the order lines. You may want to copy the code inside that tag
6. Go back to the "QWeb Views", create a view which inherits `sale.report_saleorder_document` and its `arch` field contains something like:

   ```
   <xpath expr="//table[hasclass('o_main_table')]" position="replace">
     <t t-if="doc.annexe">
       <!-- Code for more than 3 items -->
     </t> <t t-else>
       <table class="table table-sm o_main_table">
         <!-- Code for 3 items or less --> 
       </table>
     </t>
   </xpath>
   ```